# Почему не работает переменная в строке?

Tags: reactjs

```js
marginTop: '${this.inputMarginTop}%'
```

Как мне вставить переменную равную числу, в marginTop в процентах

style={{marginLeft: 10, marginBottom: 8, marginTop: '${this.inputMarginTop}%'}}

this.inputMarginTop есть, выводил в консоль

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для использования [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) Нужно использовать другой вид кавычек:

```
`${this.inputMarginTop}%`
```

В противном случае будет обычная строка без подстановки.

Пример:

```js
var inputMarginTop = 10;
console.log('${inputMarginTop}%');
console.log(`${inputMarginTop}%`);
```